# Shift values from array into one array without key

Tags: php, arrays

Having trouble with array manipulation, my array

```
[time] => Array
     (
       [0] => Array
          (
           [total_time] => 02:10:00
          )

       [1] => Array
          (
           [total_time] => 01:05:00
          )

       [2] => Array
          (
           [total_time] => 00:50:00
          )
  )
```

I wish to get

```
$total_time = ('02:10:00', '01:05:00', '00:50:00');
```

I have try with foreach

```
 foreach ($data['time'] as $key) {
    array_push($total_time, $key['total_time']);
 }
```

But my output is:

```
print_r($total_time) = 3
```

Is there any way to get this

```
$total_time = ('02:10:00', '01:05:00', '00:50:00');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like you were doing with foreach or with [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which is simpler:

```
// you could use a foreach loop like you did
$total_time = [];
foreach ($data['time'] as $key) {
    $total_time[] = $key['total_time'];
}

// or array_column
$total_time = array_column($data['time'], 'total_time');
```